# Handling custom pop-ups (not the default windows one) through selenium webdriver (3.x)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, popup

I want to automate a scenario.

When the browser lands on the website, there is a warning pop-up that requires a response to the prompt: **Do you want to proceed?**

There are two options **Leave** and **Continue**.

I am trying to switch the control with the following functions but its not working.

```
    Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
    driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
```

Comment: What error or exception you see when you execute `driver.switchTo().alert();`?

Comment: Right-click on the alert. Do you get a context menu that shows Inspect element, etc? If so, it's HTML and not a JS alert so the `Alert` class won't work. Instead treat it like any other HTML and click the button you want.

Comment: Yes i can see inspect element on right click.

Answer (score 1):

If its JavaScript alert, then `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();` should work by accepting the default. 
Is this pop-up or modal window? 
Did you try to switch to window and click on the button? 
Also, which browser are you using? JavaScript alert might needs to handled differently based on the browser.
If its modal or window, then `getWindowHandle()` should work fine.

```
String newWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
//Switching to new window
driver.findElement(By.id("buttonId"));
//Switching back to default/main window
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: It's a modal window.  Browser - Firefox.  Its HTML as I can right click on it and can inspect element.

Comment: If its modal or window, then `getWindowHandle()` should work fine. Else please provide us the error you are getting.