# Popup messages with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing a website with validation etc. when the user types something incorrectly in each field and clicks save, a popup with the information appears. All those information are in the functions in the code (there is no JSON) file with them. My question is, how can I test them with selenium so when I'm writing a test script (in Java), so when the script is running they also show up on the console? I hope I explained my problem well.

Comment: Can you please add screenshot of popup with question? is that javascript popup, iframe, child window?

Comment: it's a javascript popup

Comment: So your question is how to handle javascript popup when it appear during testing?

Comment: Yes, exactly :) and I want the message from the popup window to appear on the console

Comment: Is that custom popup or browser default javascript popup?

Comment: It's a custom one

Comment: Did you look at this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796726/handling-custom-pop-ups-not-the-default-windows-one-through-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't really solve my problem. These popups show up for like 3 seconds and disappear. There are no accept buttons etc.

Comment: Does that popup comes randomly or on specific action?

Comment: They appear when you, for example, typed forbidden signs in field Name and you try to save changes. When you click Save the popup window appears for 3 seconds and disappears.

Comment: if you really want to interact with that popup to verify validation or something then first ask developer to increase appear time if possible. then try your code. Also please share code what you tried and that popup screenshot so can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Get Text From Pop Up:

```
String popUpText = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
```

Accept Pop up Message:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```